# Why does the code send data successful after 3 times?

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth

I am creating a bluetooth connection with a pic microcontroller. I use the HC-06 as the bluetooth module. I am sure that the pic is correctly coded because when I use a premade application it works 100%. But when I try to use my own made app it only works after 3 times. Let me explain this better.

The application I made is pretty simple just a button with a click event behind it, when the button is clicked is should send data as a string to the write function, that should send the data to the pic.

But what happens is that it only works every 3 times. So when I push the button 3 times it does work. I am not sure what the problem is and why it is so specifically 3 times.

```
private void writeData(string data)
{
        try
        {
            outStream = btSocket.OutputStream;
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Fout bij het verzenden " + e.Message);
        }

        string message = data;

        byte[] msgBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

        try
        {
            outStream.Write(msgBuffer, 0, msgBuffer.Length);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Fout bij het verzenden " + e.Message);
        }
}
```

This is the function for writing data to the pic microcontroller.

```
ServiceLocator.bluetoothService.WriteData("D2O\0");
```

This is the data I send to the pic MCU. In the ServiceLocator and bluetoothService is nothing special, these are just here so I can call write from main.

I have tested what kind of data comes in the []byte with:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message)
```

and this is exactly the same data as what was sent with the on click event.

A possible solution is:

```
       try
        {
            outStream.Write(msgBuffer, 0, msgBuffer.Length);
            outStream.Write(msgBuffer, 0, msgBuffer.Length);
            outStream.Write(msgBuffer, 0, msgBuffer.Length);
        }
```

But this sends the item 3 times and I think this is not the appropriate way to fix it.

Comment: Have you checked if it's possible to Flush() your output stream, when you have written to it, as some output stream buffer data to improve it's performance.

Comment: Yea tried that as well after the data was send the flush() but didn't work as well. It took again 3 times to trigger

Comment: Does the bluetoothService/outputStream implement IDisposable or do you also need to call etc. Close() by yourself ?

Comment: Could you explain by what you mean. I did try first to write(), flush() and than close() but that didnt work as well

Comment: I'm running out of ideas - only thing left is if your bluetooth device class have some properties you can play with - like AutoFlush = True or setting a BufferSize or something.

Do you have the implementation of the BluetoothDevice or is it a nuget package or ?

Comment: I think I just found the solution! I will answer it in just a minute not sure why this does work perhaps you could shine you light on it!

Comment: This isn't the answer yet... This UTF32 triggers my interrupt all the timer (this is a good thing) but that incoming message is not exact the same so when I compare my incoming message with a premade message it won't trigger all the time, so problem solved in some way, because with ASCII the intterupt triggerd once in 3 times but the message was always clear for compare after the third time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer.

What I did was connected a module to my PC so I could read the outgoing message from my phone. When I knew what was send by my phone I downloaden a serial terminal app and did the same, so I could see what the app send.

What I found out is that the app's message also sends a \r\n (carriage return and feedline). So I implemented that as well in my ASCII encoding and it works as expected.

So this is what I changed :

```
byte[] msgBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message + "\r\n");
```

Thanks for the help anyways